# Executing php shows mib files missing

Tags: php, apache

Everytime I executing a PHP script, my apache error log get flooded with these error messages:

```
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging, referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMPv2-SMI): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (NOTIFICATION-LOG-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (UCD-SNMP-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (UCD-DEMO-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-TARGET-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (NET-SNMP-AGENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (DISMAN-EVENT-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (UCD-DLMOD-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
[Thu Mar 21 20:17:54 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 0 in (none), referer: http://localhost/login.html
```

Now I have read a lot of posts which mention that I need to copy the MIB files from ext (or extras) folder and then create an environment variable MIBDIR to point to that folder. My problem is that these *.MIB files don't exist anywhere on my machine... How on earth do I get rid of these errors ?

Comment: PS C:\Users\Pranav\Desktop> php -m
    No log handling enabled - turning on stderr logging
    Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
    Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
    ...
    ...
    Cannot find module (SNMP-MPD-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
    Cannot find module (SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
    Cannot find module (SNMP-NOTIFICATION-MIB): At line 1 in (none)
    Cannot find module (SNMPv2-TM): At line 1 in (none)
    [PHP Modules]
    bcmath
    bz2
    calendar
    Core
    ctype
    curl
    ...

    PS C:\Users\Pranav\Desktop>

Comment: PHP doesn't normally need mib files. Are you using a particular extension that is trying to load them?